# Sandbox Paypal Error code 10747 Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, sandbox

I am trying to implement do-direct payment in my asp.net C# application
It returns error "10747 This transaction cannot be processed." I have searched the issue on Paypal it says me Invalid IP Address you are using in request but I am sending valid IP address in Request but Issue still remains.

I am passing this string in req

> USER=zubairM2_api1.gmail.com&PWD=1363863579&SIGNATURE=AdEe9v7mbAer1GkOkSH-kFPUdzT5A5hUkaOZ9uanrK0fBmplr9Qlk6.a&METHOD=DoDirectPayment&CREDITCARDTYPE=&ACCT=4111111111111111&EXPDATE=062016&CVV2=123&AMT=56&FIRSTNAME=Muhammad&LASTNAME=ZUbair&IPADDRESS= 255.255.255.255&STREET=jaranwala&CITY=Faislabad&STATE=AZ&COUNTRY=USA&ZIP=69000&CURRENCYCODE=USD&VERSION=50.0

Comment: may be they except a fixed IP Address not every IP address.

Comment: I have tried both fixed and dynamic IP address but same error:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a different card number.  The card number you are using is a Payflow test card number.  You need to use a test card number that was generated from the sandbox.  Try using one of these [card numbers](http://ccaples.com/index.php/misc/tools-and-stuff/cc-num-gen) towards the top of the page.